# Print content of an activity in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, printing, xamarin.android

I'd like to print the content of the layout of an Activity in a Xamarin.Droid project (by print I mean send what's displayed on the screen to a printer wirelessly to be printed out).

I tried following the steps on the Xamarin blog post (https://blog.xamarin.com/native-printing-with-android/) but the code seems incomplete/unclear. Does anyone have a complete solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried following the steps on the Xamarin blog post (https://blog.xamarin.com/native-printing-with-android/) but the code seems incomplete/unclear. Does anyone have a complete solution to achieve this?

According to the blog you posted, you need to create your own adapter to implement `PrintDocumentAdapter` like below:

```
public class MyPrintDocumentAdapter : PrintDocumentAdapter
{

    View view;
    Context context;
    PrintedPdfDocument document;
    float scale;

    public MyPrintDocumentAdapter(Context context, View view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override void OnLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras)
    {
        document = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, newAttributes);

        CalculateScale(newAttributes);

        //set the printed PDF attributes
        var printInfo = new PrintDocumentInfo
            .Builder("MyPrint.pdf")
            .SetContentType(PrintContentType.Document)
            .SetPageCount(1)
            .Build();

        callback.OnLayoutFinished(printInfo, true);
    }

    public override void OnWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback)
    {
        PrintedPdfDocument.Page page = document.StartPage(0);

        page.Canvas.Scale(scale, scale);

        view.Draw(page.Canvas);

        document.FinishPage(page);

        WritePrintedPdfDoc(destination);

        document.Close();

        document.Dispose();

        callback.OnWriteFinished(pages);
    }

    void CalculateScale(PrintAttributes newAttributes)
    {
        int dpi = Math.Max(newAttributes.GetResolution().HorizontalDpi, newAttributes.GetResolution().VerticalDpi);

        int leftMargin = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.MinMargins.LeftMils / 1000);
        int rightMargin = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.MinMargins.RightMils / 1000);
        int topMargin = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.MinMargins.TopMils / 1000);
        int bottomMargin = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.MinMargins.BottomMils / 1000);

        int w = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.GetMediaSize().WidthMils / 1000) - leftMargin - rightMargin;
        int h = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.GetMediaSize().HeightMils / 1000) - topMargin - bottomMargin;

        scale = Math.Min((float)document.PageContentRect.Width() / w, (float)document.PageContentRect.Height() / h);
    }

    void WritePrintedPdfDoc(ParcelFileDescriptor destination)
    {
        var javaStream = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(destination.FileDescriptor);
        var osi = new OutputStreamInvoker(javaStream);
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            document.WriteTo(mem);
            var bytes = mem.ToArray();
            osi.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }

}
```

And use this `MyPrintDocumentAdapter` somewhere in your to be printed Activity:

```
var printManager = (PrintManager)GetSystemService(Context.PrintService);
var content = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mRoot);
var printAdapter = new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(this, content);
var printJob = printManager.Print("MyPrintJob", printAdapter, null);
```

For detailed tutorial, you can refer to [Print Custom Document](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html).

And here is the [Reference of PrintDocumentAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintDocumentAdapter.html).